# Making a basic query on PSQL does not display anything

Tags: postgresql, command-line, psql

I have connected to my PSQL database on command line and can run commands like `\dt` or similar just fine.

However, when I type in a basic query such as `SELECT * FROM myTable` and hit return, it does not display anything and just goes to the next line waiting for another command.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You need to terminate the query with `;`

`SELECT * FROM myTable;`

Comment: OMG... that was it !

Answer (score 7):

There is actually a less obvious cause of the above. If you've ommitted a closing bracket (`)`) somewhere in the query, you'll get the same behaviour. E.g.

```
SELECT *
    FROM some_table
    WHERE (NOW() - date_value;
```

It won't attempt to execute the statement until it gets a closing `);` before it spits out a syntax error. While the above is fairly obvious where the issue it, it gets a lot trickier to spot with more complex queries. To get out of it, close with a bracket `);` which will still resolve and spit out the syntax error so you can continue and correct.

A way to spot if this is the case, is to use the Up arrow through your history - if you're not seeing your previously typed (but not yet executed) statements, then you know you're still in a state where it's trying to close the statement before attempting a syntax check.

The issue isn't limited to brackets, but any other closing symbol such as quotes. The trick is to pay attention to the `psql` prompt as it shows the parsing state. E.g.;

- `DATABASE=>` the `=>` means all is normal and it's parsing a single line
- `DATABASE->` the `->` means you're on a new line and likely missing a `;`
- `DATABASE(>` the `(>` means you haven't closed a bracket
- `DATABASE'>` the `'>` means you haven't closed a quote.

Etc, you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this exact issue by clicking the maximize button in the top right corner of the query terminal. (PGADMIN4 - PostgreSQL 15)

I'm using PostgreSQL 15 and was running queries. I then maximized the query terminal, and following that, I was no longer able to view the query that was ran successfully. I then clicked the maximize screen and found that the results had simply been hidden behind the maximized query terminal.

Hope this helps!